# Event created from Publisher Action not showing in All Company Chatter feed

Tags: chatter, publisher

Is anyone familiar with this behavior?
I am using the publisher action to enter an Event and it produces the Event and a Chatter post. But the Chatter post does not show up in the All Company feed in the Chatter tab for people who have access to the Account, Event, etc.
The picture is the publisher action on a test Account and the result of a previous one.

[image: Picture of the publisher action and the result]

It does not show in the All Company view in the Chatter tab.

[image: allco]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Thanks for your question. In order for the feed to show up in All company feed, it has to meet any of the following conditions:

1) People in your company
2) Public groups
3) Private groups you are a member of
4) Feed tracked changes for records and fields and system-generated posts, if someone liked or commented on the post. You must have access to the record to see the post.

See the documentation at:
https://help.salesforce.com/HTViewHelpDoc?id=collab_feed_filters.htm&language=en_US

In your case, you have a record create feed, which is a system-generated post. If you or someone else clicks "like" or comment on the post that feed it'll meet condition 4), and should show up in the All Company view.

Comment: I understand now. It is an odd distinction and it makes it hard for people to use the All Company Chatter feed to monitor everyone's actions. I guess there are places/reasons this makes sense. Thanks

Comment: Is there a workaround? If I make the publisher call a custom visualforce with a Create Event function would that go into the all company feed? Thanks

Comment: Could I use the publisher to make a meeting that WOULD show in the All company?